# access specific cell from excel add-in vsto

Tags: vsto

How can I access as specific cell B1 from my excel add-in vsto in microsoft visual studio 2010.

`Globals.Sheet1.Range(“B3”).Value` this does not work as it seems its the syntax for excel document instead of excel add-in.

---

edit
this seems to work

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet activeSheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;
    var currentCells = activeSheet.get_Range("A1", "E1");
    currentCells.Select();
```

but then how do I select specific values in `currentCells`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
var excel = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
var activeSheet = (Worksheet)excel.ActiveSheet;
var cell = activeSheet.Range["B1", Type.Missing];
var content = cell.Value2;
```

Comment: since its .Net 4.0 you don't even need the Type.Missing do you Mathias? (nit picky i know lol)

Answer (score 0):

You could do [Range.Find(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.find.aspx), and then FindNext, adding found cells to list

Alternatively, you could iterate over all Range.Item[i,j] for i = 1 to Range.Rows.Count (==1 in your case) and j=1 to Range.Columns.Count like [this](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=11208&page=1) and check the values of individual cells as you go.

Use Application.Union to combine multiple Ranges from the acquired list and do Select() on the combined range